# How to set the QQuickItem position at a precise frame from C++?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qml, core-motion

My mobile application uses the `OpenGL` under `QML` paradigm.

The camera orientation of my GL scene is synced to the Motion Sensor (magnetometer and accelerometer) of the mobile device. I'm also displaying a 2D label on top of that 3D scene whose position on screen needs to correspond to a given 3D position in my GL scene. These labels are regular QML items that I control from the C++ side of my app.

To do this I make a direct connection to the `QQuickWindow::beforeSynchronising()` signal where the camera orientation is synced with the motion sensor. I then project a 3D point on the screen to find the position of the label and finally make a call to `QQuickItem::setPosition()`.

The GL scene is rendered as usual using a direct connection to the `QQuickWindow::beforeRendering()` signal.

```
MyAppController::MyAppController() : QObject() {
    connect(window, SIGNAL(beforeSynchronising()), this, SLOT(sync()), Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(window, SIGNAL(beforeRendering()), this, SLOT(render()), Qt::DirectConnection);

    m_camera = ...; // create camera
    m_scene = ...;  // create GL scene
    m_quickItem = ...; // load label QML item

    // start updating the window at a constant frame rate
    QTimer* timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect (timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
    timer->start(1000.0 / 60.0);   // 60 FPS
}

MyAppController::sync() {
    m_camera->syncWithMotionSensor();

    // use camera matrix to calculate the projection of a 3D point on the screen
    QPointF pos = ...;  
    m_quickItem->setPosition(pos);  // set the label position
}

MyAppController::render() {
    m_scene->draw(); // OpenGL code
}
```

All is well, except that my labels seem to be one frame too late compared to my GL scene and I think I understand why : Calling `QQuickItem::setPosition()` from the QSGRendering thread is apparently too late for the `QSGNode` to get updated for that frame. An update is scheduled for that item but it doesn't take effect until the next frame. Hence the 1 frame delay.

You might think that it's not that bad, however, it does create a strange effect and does not help with reading what's on the label because the eyes are also following the background (remember the camera is synced with the device motion sensor).

I tried using the `QQuickWindow::afterAnimating()` signal but the delay is even bigger. This is normal since this signal is emitted from the GUI thread and thus we have even less control on which frame the QSGRenderThread will get synced.

So my question is, how can I achieve the positioning of a QML item from C++ at a precise frame ? Is this even possible using QML ? Would it be better if my labels were pure C++ QQuickItems and if instead of calling setPosition() I used my own function that makes sure the QSGNode will receive the update ?

Answer (score 1):

So the answer is to simply sync the camera and the label's position ***after*** rendering the GL scene. This way we are sure that at the next frame the label's position will be taken into account.
Final solution looks like this:

```
MyAppController::sync() {
    m_scene->prepare();  // uses the camera matrix from previous frame    
    m_camera->syncWithMotionSensor();  // update camera matrix
    // use camera matrix to calculate the projection of a 3D point on the screen
    QPointF pos = ...;  
    m_quickItem->setPosition(pos);  // set the label position, will be updated on the next frame
}

MyAppController::render() {
    m_scene->draw(); // execute OpenGL code
}
```